# How to convert XText to XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

Say i have a XText declaration something like

> XText FirstName = new XText("Rufus");

How to convert it to XElement?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   XElement element = new XElement("FirstName",FirstName);
```